# Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools missing ARM compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, arm

I installed the Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017, but it does not give me an option to install compilers for ARM. This is what I see on the Build Tools installer:
[image: Build Tools installer]

But the ARM option is missing, and the "arm" folder in the installed directory is missing. It's normally visible here on a full Visual Studio installer:
[image: Visual Studio Enterprise installer]

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Your installer is for "VS Build Tools". I'd presume that the ARM compiler and stuff are included only with the normal IDE installation.

Comment: @tambre But why should ARM be excluded when x86/x64 is included? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: The [Visual Studio Build Tools 2015](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools), which is a separate download, explicitly says *"These tools allow you to build C++ libraries and applications targeting Windows desktop."* Can't see that this policy changed for 2017.